# Why isn't subprocess.run working in a seperate thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, text, subprocess, python-multithreading

I'm using `subprocess.run()` to run a .txt file containing python code. That python code may contain a while loop. I need the rest of my code to run while that is running. The obvious way to do this is using the  `threading` module, when I put `subprocess.run()` in a separate thread, it returns something like `Enable tracemalloc to see traceback` (error) or something like that.

```
#.txt file
while True:
  print("Hello")
```

```py
#.py file:
import subprocess
import threading as th

def thread():
  subprocess.run('python foo.txt')
th2=th.Thread(target=thread)
th2.start()
#code here
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: show code which makes this problem. We can't see code and we can't read in your mind - you have to show all details in question (not in comments) as text (not image)

Comment: why do you use `subprocess` to run python code? Why not `import` code and run it normally?

Comment: I cant import it because I need to run it in a separate thread. I haven't really tried that really and don't exactly know how to run by importing

Comment: So import it and run it in a separate thread?

Comment: you can `import` it in separated thread. You can use it as any other module - if you have file `script.py` then you can use `import script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a thread here at all, since the subprocess is, well, a separate process.

You do, however, need to switch from the blocking `.run()` convenience function to [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects):

```
import subprocess
import sys
import time
proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'foo.txt'])
# ... do other things here...
time.sleep(1)
proc.kill()
```